# How to setup App Autoscaler in PCF while using Blue-Green-Deployment

Tags: autoscaling, cloud-foundry

I have my setup ready for `Blue-Green deployment` and it is working fine.
I have an instance of`App Autoscaler` as well and it's enabled for few apps too and working as expected.

Scenario where I am struggling is whenever I deploy a new version of app using `Blue-Green Deployment` approach, my new app version(green) becomes active and currently active app(blue) becomes ice app(dead) so all the `Autoscaler` configuration goes away with ice app.
Not sure how to add all `Autoscaler` configuration to the new app version(green) and handle this case.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no automatic way to copy that over, but you can script the rules using the app autoscaler cli plugin or use the app autoscaler cli plugin's manifest support (separate from your application manifest.yml).

https://network.pivotal.io/products/pcf-app-autoscaler/

Download the version corresponding to your PCF version (1.x plugin for PCF 2.1 and older, or 2.x plugin version for PCF 2.2+).

You can see instructions for using the plugin here.

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/appsman-services/autoscaler/using-autoscaler-cli.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for sharing this info, I was going through this plugin and completed my POC also on local which was working fine, but couldn't get approval to install the same on my Jenkins box so dropped that idea.. I thought there must be other way around to get this thing done, but I think I need to work bit more hard to setup this autoscaler plugin anyhow.

Comment: I cannot find this in the documentation but as far as I remember, you'll need to restage the application after using this cli. This breaks the blue-green flow, your app is going to be down during the restage.

Comment: @Tamas - which cli command are you referring to, the one that requires a restart?

Answer (score 0):

A trick we were using is that you can pass in a smoke test script to the blue green deployment command. You can do the tests first and if they pass, you can run the cf commands to bind the service to your app, configure rules and restage the green app before the routes are switched from blue to green.

Comment: What do you mean "pass in  smoke test script"?